# filtering entire data frame based on a unique value and create a new column in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, filtering

I have been trying to figure this out for hours but I can't seem to get the solution I am looking for. How can you filter a data frame in R for a certain unique value and then create a new column with the column names that met that condition?

**I have this data frame:**

```
 dput(head(df1,10))
structure(list(WMA = c("20", "19", "19", "19", "18", "19", "20", 
"20", "20", "19"), Waterbody = c("02040201070010-01", "02040202060040-01", 
"02040202060050-01", "02040202060060-01", "02040202150070-01", 
"02040202030080-01", "02040201080010-01", "02040201080020-01", 
"02040201080030-01", "02040202070010-01"), Name = c("Back Creek (above Yardville-H Sq Road)", 
"Barton Run (above Kettle Run Road)", "Barton Run (below Kettle Run Road)", 
"Bear Swamp River", "Birch Creek", "Bisphams Mill Creek (below McDonalds Br)", 
"Blacks Creek (above 40d06m10s)", "Blacks Creek (Bacons Run to 40d06m10s)", 
"Blacks Creek (below Bacons Run)", "Bobbys Run"), DO = c("Insufficient Data", 
"Non-attaining", "Non-attaining", "Insufficient Data", "Attaining", 
"Attaining", "Attaining", "Attaining", "Attaining", "Insufficient Data"
), `DO Trout` = c("N/A", "N/A", "N/A", "N/A", "N/A", "N/A", "N/A", 
"N/A", "N/A", "N/A"), pH = c("Insufficient Data", "Non-attaining", 
"Non-attaining", "Insufficient Data", "Attaining", "Attaining", 
"Attaining", "Attaining", "Attaining", "Insufficient Data"), 
    `Total Phosphorus` = c("Non-attaining", "Attaining", "Non-attaining", 
    "Insufficient Data", "Insufficient Data", "Non-attaining", 
    "Non-attaining", "Non-attaining", "Non-attaining", "Insufficient Data"
    ), Nitrate = c("Attaining", "Attaining", "Attaining", "Insufficient Data", 
    "Insufficient Data", "Attaining", "Attaining", "Attaining", 
    "Attaining", "Insufficient Data"), `Total Suspended Solids` = c("Attaining", 
    "Attaining", "Attaining", "Insufficient Data", "Insufficient Data", 
    "Insufficient Data", "Attaining", "Attaining", "Non-attaining", 
    "Insufficient Data"), `Total Dissolved Solids` = c("Insufficient Data", 
    "Attaining", "Attaining", "Insufficient Data", "Insufficient Data", 
    "Insufficient Data", "Attaining", "Attaining", "Attaining", 
    "Insufficient Data"), Turbidity = c("Insufficient Data", 
    "Attaining", "Attaining", "Insufficient Data", "Attaining", 
    "Insufficient Data", "Attaining", "Attaining", "Attaining", 
    "Insufficient Data"), `Unionized Ammonia` = c("Attaining", 
    "Attaining", "Attaining", "Insufficient Data", "Attaining", 
    "Insufficient Data", "Attaining", "Attaining", "Attaining", 
    "Insufficient Data"), `Unionized Ammonia Trout` = c("N/A", 
    "N/A", "N/A", "N/A", "N/A", "N/A", "N/A", "N/A", "N/A", "N/A"
    ), E.coli = c("Insufficient Data", "Attaining", "Attaining", 
    "Attaining", "Attaining", "Attaining", "Attaining", "Non-attaining", 
    "Non-attaining", "Attaining"), Enterococcus = c("N/A", "N/A", 
    "N/A", "N/A", "N/A", "N/A", "N/A", "N/A", "N/A", "N/A"), 
    `Total Coliform` = c("N/A", "N/A", "N/A", "N/A", "N/A", "N/A", 
    "N/A", "N/A", "N/A", "N/A")), .Names = c("WMA", "Waterbody", 
"Name", "DO", "DO Trout", "pH", "Total Phosphorus", "Nitrate", 
"Total Suspended Solids", "Total Dissolved Solids", "Turbidity", 
"Unionized Ammonia", "Unionized Ammonia Trout", "E.coli", "Enterococcus", 
"Total Coliform"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I want to perform a filter on every column to see which ones have the unique value, "Non-attaining". Then I want to create a new column based on that that shows the column names where this is met.

**Here's a spread sheet of what I want:**

[image]
I tried using the dplyr verbs but haven't gotten any success. Any help or guidance is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you please make sure that the image corresponding to your expected outcome is showing up?

Comment: @Ozan147 Sorry. Fixed it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `which(cond, arr.ind=TRUE)`. Here's how with data.table:

```
library(data.table)
DT = as.data.table(df1)

w = as.data.table(which(DT == "Non-attaining", arr.ind = TRUE))[, .(cols = toString(names(DT)[col])), by=row]

DT[w$row, NAcols := w$cols]
```

which gives...

```
>     DT[, c(1, 17)]
    WMA                                           NAcols
 1:  20                                 Total Phosphorus
 2:  19                                           DO, pH
 3:  19                         DO, pH, Total Phosphorus
 4:  19                                             <NA>
 5:  18                                             <NA>
 6:  19                                 Total Phosphorus
 7:  20                                 Total Phosphorus
 8:  20                         Total Phosphorus, E.coli
 9:  20 Total Phosphorus, Total Suspended Solids, E.coli
10:  19                                             <NA>
```

Comment: Thank you! I would like to also keep the WMA, Waterbody, and Name columns .. is this possible?

Comment: @KWANGER Yes, you can select cols with a vector of numbers or names, like `DT[, c("WMA", "Waterbody", "Name", "NAcols")]` (I only printed 1 & 17 since the table is so big)

Answer (score 4):

You can apply a custom function like so:

```
myfun <- function(x) {
    paste(colnames(df)[x == "Non-attaining"], collapse=", ")
}

df$newcol <- apply(df, 1, myfun)
```

Or do it all in one fell swoop:

```
df$newcol <- apply(df, 1, function(x) paste(colnames(df)[x == "Non-attaining"], collapse=", "))
```

Comment: Works fine on your example data for me.  Check that you have no typos in "Non-attaining" (capitalization matters).  Also note that I've named your data `df`.  Change `df` to whatever you call you dataframe.

Comment: data frames are coerced to matrix by apply, so your conversion is not necessary, unless you want to make it explicit on purpose

Comment: Thanks -- I'll simplify my answer.  Too bad the helpfiles never list this kind of information and we're left to sort it out on our own.  But you're right, the source code for `apply` has `as.matrix` right at the top :)

Answer (score 4):

If you want a tidyverse solution, you can:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>% 
  select(WMA, Waterbody, Name) %>% 
  left_join(df1 %>% 
              gather(ColName, Value, -WMA, -Waterbody, -Name) %>% 
              filter(grepl("Non-attaining", Value, ignore.case = TRUE, perl = TRUE)) %>% 
              group_by(WMA, Waterbody, Name) %>% 
              summarise(Imp = paste(ColName, collapse = ',')) %>% 
              ungroup(), by = c("WMA", "Waterbody", "Name"))
```

This gives:

```
# A tibble: 10 x 4
   WMA   Waterbody         Name                                     Imp                                           
   <chr> <chr>             <chr>                                    <chr>                                         
 1 20    02040201070010-01 Back Creek (above Yardville-H Sq Road)   Total Phosphorus                              
 2 19    02040202060040-01 Barton Run (above Kettle Run Road)       DO,pH                                         
 3 19    02040202060050-01 Barton Run (below Kettle Run Road)       DO,pH,Total Phosphorus                        
 4 19    02040202060060-01 Bear Swamp River                         NA                                            
 5 18    02040202150070-01 Birch Creek                              NA                                            
 6 19    02040202030080-01 Bisphams Mill Creek (below McDonalds Br) Total Phosphorus                              
 7 20    02040201080010-01 Blacks Creek (above 40d06m10s)           Total Phosphorus                              
 8 20    02040201080020-01 Blacks Creek (Bacons Run to 40d06m10s)   Total Phosphorus,E.coli                       
 9 20    02040201080030-01 Blacks Creek (below Bacons Run)          Total Phosphorus,Total Suspended Solids,E.coli
10 19    02040202070010-01 Bobbys Run                               NA
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is one more `tidyverse` solution that doesn't involve reshaping the data. Instead we can use `pmap` to map across the rows of the dataframe and then collapse the resulting character vectors.

```r
library(tidyverse)
tbl <- structure(list(WMA = c("20", "19", "19", "19", "18", "19", "20", "20", "20", "19"), Waterbody = c("02040201070010-01", "02040202060040-01", "02040202060050-01", "02040202060060-01", "02040202150070-01", "02040202030080-01", "02040201080010-01", "02040201080020-01", "02040201080030-01", "02040202070010-01"), Name = c("Back Creek (above Yardville-H Sq Road)", "Barton Run (above Kettle Run Road)", "Barton Run (below Kettle Run Road)", "Bear Swamp River", "Birch Creek", "Bisphams Mill Creek (below McDonalds Br)", "Blacks Creek (above 40d06m10s)", "Blacks Creek (Bacons Run to 40d06m10s)", "Blacks Creek (below Bacons Run)", "Bobbys Run"), DO = c("Insufficient Data", "Non-attaining", "Non-attaining", "Insufficient Data", "Attaining", "Attaining", "Attaining", "Attaining", "Attaining", "Insufficient Data"), `DO Trout` = c("N/A", "N/A", "N/A", "N/A", "N/A", "N/A", "N/A", "N/A", "N/A", "N/A"), pH = c("Insufficient Data", "Non-attaining", "Non-attaining", "Insufficient Data", "Attaining", "Attaining", "Attaining", "Attaining", "Attaining", "Insufficient Data"), `Total Phosphorus` = c("Non-attaining", "Attaining", "Non-attaining", "Insufficient Data", "Insufficient Data", "Non-attaining", "Non-attaining", "Non-attaining", "Non-attaining", "Insufficient Data"), Nitrate = c("Attaining", "Attaining", "Attaining", "Insufficient Data", "Insufficient Data", "Attaining", "Attaining", "Attaining", "Attaining", "Insufficient Data"), `Total Suspended Solids` = c("Attaining", "Attaining", "Attaining", "Insufficient Data", "Insufficient Data", "Insufficient Data", "Attaining", "Attaining", "Non-attaining", "Insufficient Data"), `Total Dissolved Solids` = c("Insufficient Data", "Attaining", "Attaining", "Insufficient Data", "Insufficient Data", "Insufficient Data", "Attaining", "Attaining", "Attaining", "Insufficient Data"), Turbidity = c("Insufficient Data", "Attaining", "Attaining", "Insufficient Data", "Attaining", "Insufficient Data", "Attaining", "Attaining", "Attaining", "Insufficient Data"), `Unionized Ammonia` = c("Attaining", "Attaining", "Attaining", "Insufficient Data", "Attaining", "Insufficient Data", "Attaining", "Attaining", "Attaining", "Insufficient Data"), `Unionized Ammonia Trout` = c("N/A", "N/A", "N/A", "N/A", "N/A", "N/A", "N/A", "N/A", "N/A", "N/A"), E.coli = c("Insufficient Data", "Attaining", "Attaining", "Attaining", "Attaining", "Attaining", "Attaining", "Non-attaining", "Non-attaining", "Attaining"), Enterococcus = c("N/A", "N/A", "N/A", "N/A", "N/A", "N/A", "N/A", "N/A", "N/A", "N/A"), `Total Coliform` = c("N/A", "N/A", "N/A", "N/A", "N/A", "N/A", "N/A", "N/A", "N/A", "N/A")), .Names = c("WMA", "Waterbody", "Name", "DO", "DO Trout", "pH", "Total Phosphorus", "Nitrate", "Total Suspended Solids", "Total Dissolved Solids", "Turbidity", "Unionized Ammonia", "Unionized Ammonia Trout", "E.coli", "Enterococcus", "Total Coliform"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

with_imp <- tbl %>%
  mutate(
    Imp = pmap(., function(...) names(list(...))[which(c(...) == "Non-attaining")]),
    Imp = Imp %>%
      map(str_c, collapse = ",") %>%
      map_if(~ length(.) == 0, ~ NA_character_) %>%
      flatten_chr
    )
with_imp[, c(1:3, 17)]
#> # A tibble: 10 x 4
#>    WMA   Waterbody      Name                    Imp                       
#>    <chr> <chr>          <chr>                   <chr>                     
#>  1 20    0204020107001~ Back Creek (above Yard~ Total Phosphorus          
#>  2 19    0204020206004~ Barton Run (above Kett~ DO,pH                     
#>  3 19    0204020206005~ Barton Run (below Kett~ DO,pH,Total Phosphorus    
#>  4 19    0204020206006~ Bear Swamp River        <NA>                      
#>  5 18    0204020215007~ Birch Creek             <NA>                      
#>  6 19    0204020203008~ Bisphams Mill Creek (b~ Total Phosphorus          
#>  7 20    0204020108001~ Blacks Creek (above 40~ Total Phosphorus          
#>  8 20    0204020108002~ Blacks Creek (Bacons R~ Total Phosphorus,E.coli   
#>  9 20    0204020108003~ Blacks Creek (below Ba~ Total Phosphorus,Total Su~
#> 10 19    0204020207001~ Bobbys Run              <NA>
```

Created on 2018-08-13 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).